# What can you 'distort'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

You can distort facts, truth, images, signals. What else can you distort?
Please give examples of using this verb.

Comment: You can distort anything that, physically, digitally or metaphorically can be changed in appearance by modifying the relative positions of its constituent elements.

Comment: Meaning, memory, magnetic field, metaphor, melting chocolate, marriage vows, music, mouth, map.  And I guess that's about it.

Comment: @Hot Licks - How does one distort melting chocolate, pray tell?

Comment: @Lambie - Like [this](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/heart-shape-made-up-melted-chocolate-26742280.jpg).

Comment: @Silenus - Yep, and marshmallows.

Comment: Could you explain why is this question getting downvotes? Am I breaking any rules of the site? I'm new to the site, want to understand what's wrong with the this question to phrase the following ones better.

Comment: When you melt chocolate, it changes consistency. I would not call that distorting....

Comment: You are at least nominally in violation of this rule:  *Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.*

Comment: @Lambie - OK, try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h767n_gaCc).

Comment: The semantic trait for the word distort (change shape while keeping the same material consistency) does  not apply to chocolate for me. Distort is a topological change. Melting a bar of chocolate is not a distortion. It's a chemical change....

Comment: @Lambie - You have a distorted sense of chocolate.

Comment: Yes, I agree that one's sense of something can be distorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can distort practically everything that has a shape. Furthermore, you can distort the truth by mixing it with falsehood.